# cursor for sql server2005

Tags: sql

This is my cursor procedure:

```
DECLARE C1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
  SELECT DISTINCT
         PPTR_MATCH_REF_NO,
         PPTR_LDGR_CODE,
         PPTR_SLMAST_ACNO,
         PPTR_PPN_STATUS
    FROM GLAS_PPN_TRANSACTIONS 
   WHERE PPTR_COMP_CODE  = @COMP_CODE
 AND ISNULL(PPTR_PPN_STATUS, 'X') = 'V'

DECLARE @MATCH_REF_NO NUMERIC(10,0),
    @LDGR_CODE    VARCHAR(MAX),
    @SLMAST_ACNO  VARCHAR(MAX),
    @PPN_STATUS   VARCHAR(2),
    @ACCT_NAME    VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN

  OPEN C1 

  FETCH NEXT FROM  C1 INTO @MATCH_REF_NO,@LDGR_CODE,@SLMAST_ACNO,@PPN_STATUS
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0

    BEGIN
        -- SET @MATCH_REF_NO  =  PPTR_MATCH_REF_NO 
        -- SET @LDGR_CODE  =  PPTR_LDGR_CODE 
        -- SET @SLMAST_ACNO  = PPTR_SLMAST_ACNO 

    SELECT @ACCT_NAME = COAD_PTY_FULL_NAME
      FROM GLAS_SBLGR_MASTERS,
           GLAS_PTY_ADDRESS 
     WHERE SLMA_COMP_CODE = @COMP_CODE
       AND SLMA_LDGRCTL_YEAR  = DBO.GLAS_VALIDATIONS_GET_OPEN_YEAR(@COMP_CODE) 
       AND SLMA_LDGRCTL_CODE  = @LDGR_CODE
       AND SLMA_STATUS  = 'A'
       AND SLMA_ACNO  = @SLMAST_ACNO
       AND COAD_COMP_CODE  = SLMA_COMP_CODE
       AND COAD_ADDR_ID  = SLMA_ADDR_ID

    IF @PPN_STATUS = 'V' 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @PPN_STATUS  = 'VER' 
        END

    FETCH NEXT FROM  C1 INTO @MATCH_REF_NO,@LDGR_CODE,@SLMAST_ACNO,@PPN_STATUS              
    END
        CLOSE C1
    END
    DEALLOCATE C1
END
```

How can I retrive `@MATCH_REF_NO`, `@LDGR_CODE`, `@SLMAST_ACNO`, `@PPN_STATUS` and `@ACCT_NAME` at the same time?

here 2 select statements is there how can i combine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this by using a common-table expression (CTE) in SQL Server 2005 - you'll get something like:

```
WITH Select1 AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
         PPTR_MATCH_REF_NO,
         PPTR_LDGR_CODE,
         PPTR_SLMAST_ACNO,
         PPTR_PPN_STATUS
    FROM GLAS_PPN_TRANSACTIONS 
   WHERE PPTR_COMP_CODE  = @COMP_CODE
 AND ISNULL(PPTR_PPN_STATUS, 'X') = 'V'
)
SELECT 
    COAD_PTY_FULL_NAME
FROM 
    GLAS_SBLGR_MASTERS, GLAS_PTY_ADDRESS, Select1
WHERE 
    SLMA_COMP_CODE = Select1.COMP_CODE
    AND SLMA_LDGRCTL_YEAR  = DBO.GLAS_VALIDATIONS_GET_OPEN_YEAR(Select1.COMP_CODE) 
    AND SLMA_LDGRCTL_CODE  = Select1.LDGR_CODE
    AND SLMA_STATUS  = 'A'
    AND SLMA_ACNO  = Select1.SLMAST_ACNO
    AND COAD_COMP_CODE  = SLMA_COMP_CODE
    AND COAD_ADDR_ID  = SLMA_ADDR_ID
```

What I cannot determine from the code you posted is how the `GLAS_SBLGR_MASTERS` and the `GLAS_PTY_ADDRESS` are joined (on what condition). Just specifying these two in the `FROM` clause should be avoided - use the standard ANSI SQL JOIN statements:

```
FROM GLAS_SBLGR_MASTERS
INNER JOIN GLAS_PTY_ADDRESS ON ???????
```

Marc